# how to combine functions for elements with consecutive IDs

Tags: jquery

Sorry if the title was confusing, i could not think of something better. Basically, what i want to do is straight forward. This is my code

```
jQUery('.button1').click(function() {
    jQuery(".box1").slideUp();
    jQuery(this).remove();
});
jQUery('.button2').click(function() {
    jQuery(".box2").slideUp();
    jQuery(this).remove();
});
jQUery('.button3').click(function() {
    jQuery(".box3").slideUp();
    jQuery(this).remove();
});
```

and so on....
Now that's pretty much a mess when i have more boxes. Is there any way i can combine them all and let jquery do the ID numbers?

Comment: Your code lacks quotes around jquery selectors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set class name for buttons (e.g. `"buttons"`) and use ID:

```
<button id="button1" class="buttons">Delete</button>
```

Then, you can make some trick to get the number from the ID:

```
$(".buttons").on("click", function() {
    var n = this.id.replace("button", "");
    $(".box" + n).slideUp();
    $(this).remove();
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/DXzKu/

Comment: +1 because you don't need to update the js everytime you add a new button/box. You just need to make sure you have the `buttons` class on the button and that the numbers match between button and box.

Comment: [Look at this clown](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10880703/601179). Some SO users are just so... talented at being stupid.

Answer (score 1):

The attribute starts-with selector ('^=) will work for your IDs, like this:

```
$('[class^="button"]').click(function() {
  //do stuff
});
```

You can get the number from clicked element and show / hide the box.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine them in one selector:

```
jQUery('#button1, #button2, #button3')...
```

Comment: but then i guess clicking any of those buttons will close ALL the boxes :|

Comment: If you use `$(this)` within your click-handler the function will only apply to the currently-clicked element.

Comment: That wouldn't make the link with the ".box".

Comment: You can use relative selectors like $(this).next() according to your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i=1; i<=3; i++) {
   $('.button'+i).click(function() {
      $(".box"+i).slideUp();
      $(this).remove();
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like below,

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
   jQUery('.button'+i).click({ i: i }, function(e) {
     jQuery(".box"+ e.data.i).slideUp();
     jQuery(this).remove();
   });
}
```

But with some markup change we can do this better.